# setting min and max date and time values in highcharts

Tags: datetime, highcharts

I am attempting to show a stacked area chart with the following java script code.
The start and end dates are javascript Date objects.

The value of the start date is 
`Sun Dec 01 2013 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)`

When setting the min and max values on the xAxis, the labels are not working correctly. If I replace the Date objects with `Date.UTC` it works.

**How do I convert the `Date` into a suitable value for `min` and `max`**?

```
        var series = _.map(data, function(dp) { return { name: dp.PartySummary.DisplayName, data: _.map(_.pluck(dp.Values, 'TotalFee') ,function(value) { return Math.round(value); }  ) }; });
        var startDate = _.first(_.sortBy(_.map(_.flatten(_.pluck(data, 'Values')), function(item) { return new Date(item.Date); })));
        var endDate = _.last(_.sortBy(_.map(_.flatten(_.pluck(data, 'Values')), function(item) { return new Date(item.Date); })));
        $('#area').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'area'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
               type: 'datetime',
                min: startDate, //Date.UTC(2011, 4, 31), // THE UTC VERSION WORKS.
                max: endDate, //Date.UTC(2012, 11, 6),
                labels: {
                    step: 1,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '13px',
                        fontFamily: 'Arial,sans-serif'
                    }
                },
                dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                    month: '%b \'%y',
                    year: '%Y'
                }
               /// categories:['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12']
            },
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650391/format-date-string-into-highcharts?rq=1
I hope this will help you

Comment: How about simply using `endDate.getTime()` and `startDate.getTime()`?

Comment: That seems to work just fine do you want to post as the answer